# Match 2 Columns and Result from 3rd Column

Tags: excel, vba, compare, multiple-columns

Need help to compare (match) 2 columns from 2 sheets and return value from 3rd column of 2nd sheet if it matches.

```
    With Range("B3:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        .Formula = "=INDEX($D:$D,MATCH(1,(Sheet1!B$1=Sheet2!$C:$C)*(Sheet1!$A3=Sheet2!$A:$A),0))"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
```

Sheet 1:

[image]

Sheet 2:

[image]

This Function is taking longer than usual if I place formula in each cell (for whole month). so trying this With function but needs a better code which should run faster. Any suggestions ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Match Columns Using a Dictionary of Dictionaries

```vb
Sub MatchColumns()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' ("A1:D13")
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = srg.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = srg.Resize(rCount).Offset(1).Value ' ("A2:D13")
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim r As Long

    For r = 1 To rCount
        Key = Data(r, 1)
        If Not dict.Exists(Key) Then
            Set dict(Key) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        End If
        dict(Key)(Data(r, 3)) = Data(r, 4)
    Next r
    
    ' Print the contents of the dictionary in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G).
'    Dim iKey As Variant
'    For Each Key In dict.Keys
'        Debug.Print Key
'        For Each iKey In dict(Key).Keys
'            Debug.Print iKey
'        Next iKey
'    Next Key
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim drrg As Range ' The Row (Column Labels, Headers) ' ("B1:E1")
    Set drrg = dws.Range("B1", dws.Cells(1, dws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    Dim rData As Variant: rData = drrg.Value
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = drrg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim dcrg As Range ' The Column (Row Labels) ' ("A3:A5")
    Set dcrg = dws.Range("A3", dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    Dim cData As Variant: cData = dcrg.Value
    rCount = dcrg.Rows.Count
    
    ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    Dim c As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        Key = cData(r, 1)
        If dict.Exists(Key) Then
            For c = 1 To cCount
                If dict(Key).Exists(rData(1, c)) Then
                    Data(r, c) = dict(Key)(rData(1, c))
                End If
            Next c
        End If
    Next r
    
    dws.Range("B3").Resize(rCount, cCount).Value = Data ' ("B3:E5")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks allot for your help.. This script worked flawlessly .. Thanks again.. So to understand the script, we are adding the data to dictionary and fetching the requirements from there ?? Like an array ?? And I'm going to test it on 2000 rows .. lets hope the script completes faster than usual..

Comment: This worked perfectly perfect and faster than expected.. Thanks again for your support.. @VBasic2008

Comment: Hi.. could you please help me on the below post if possible.. this is continuation of my query..     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72063615/filter-2-columns-based-on-date-time-range      https://stackoverflow.com/users/9814069/vbasic2008

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365 you can make this easily with FILTER:

[image]

My formula in cell G4 is:

```
=FILTER($D$2:$D$13;($A$2:$A$13=$F4)*($C$2:$C$13=G$2))
```

Drag to right and down

If you don't have Excel 365 you can do it with a complext formula:

```
=INDEX($D$1:$D$13;SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$13=$F4)*--($C$2:$C$13=G$2)*FILA($D$2:$D$13)))
```

Notice that the part `SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$13=$F4)*--($C$2:$C$13=G$2)*FILA($D$2:$D$13))` will return the absolute row number of where the data is located so in INDEX you need to reference the whole column or substract properly (that's why I chose from row 1 including headers as first argument of INDEX).

Answer (score 0):

This uses an array formula to populate B3:E6 simultaneously

```
With Sheet1.Range("B3:E" & Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    .FormulaArray = "=INDEX(Sheet2!$D$2:$D$13,MATCH(Sheet1!A3:A5&Sheet1!B1:E1,Sheet2!A2:A13&Sheet2!C2:C13,0))"
    .Value2 = .Value2
End With
```