# Filter 2 columns based on Date & time Range

Tags: excel, vba

Need help on filtering 2 columns based on date & time and delete the entries other than the nearest date & time range.

[image: screenshot of range]

Now I want the result based on the range per the example below and delete the rest..

I want the Final result that should be

1. between Column C Date + 1 [eg: between (2022-Apr-22) to (2022-Apr-23)]
2. between Time from Column D [eg: between (10AM) to next Day (10AM)]
3. And keep the nearest Time & delete the rest.

Just FYI., this is the script I've..

```
Sub MatchColumns()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' ("A1:D13")
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = srg.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = srg.Resize(rCount).Offset(1).Value ' ("A2:D13")
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim r As Long

    For r = 1 To rCount
        Key = Data(r, 1)
        If Not dict.Exists(Key) Then
            Set dict(Key) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        End If
        dict(Key)(Data(r, 3)) = Data(r, 4)
    Next r
    
    ' Print the contents of the dictionary in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G).
'    Dim iKey As Variant
'    For Each Key In dict.Keys
'        Debug.Print Key
'        For Each iKey In dict(Key).Keys
'            Debug.Print iKey
'        Next iKey
'    Next Key
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim drrg As Range ' The Row (Column Labels, Headers) ' ("B1:E1")
    Set drrg = dws.Range("B1", dws.Cells(1, dws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    Dim rData As Variant: rData = drrg.Value
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = drrg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim dcrg As Range ' The Column (Row Labels) ' ("A3:A5")
    Set dcrg = dws.Range("A3", dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    Dim cData As Variant: cData = dcrg.Value
    rCount = dcrg.Rows.Count
    
    ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    Dim c As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        Key = cData(r, 1)
        If dict.Exists(Key) Then
            For c = 1 To cCount
                If dict(Key).Exists(rData(1, c)) Then
                    Data(r, c) = dict(Key)(rData(1, c))
                End If
            Next c
        End If
    Next r
    
    dws.Range("B3").Resize(rCount, cCount).Value = Data ' ("B3:E5")
    
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Not sure what VBA code you've got already, but you could simply filter table by column "Exit Date & Time" to show unwanted result and delete only visible rows

Comment: Please, post the code you've tried and where are you stuck

Comment: Updated the code I'm using.. @VBasic2008

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, as I have not completely understood the criteria for the filter.
however, I am sure you will be able to adjust the code below to your needs.

And, of course, it is most likely not the best approach, - but should work.

The main idea, is to create and convert datetime values to the `TimeSerial` which can be used to filter column D.
Later filter data to show rows which are not needed and delete visible.
At the end, clear filter and show remaining data.

Please note, place it after `dws.Range("B3").Resize(rCount, cCount).Value = Data ' ("B3:E5")`

example:

```
Sub MatchColumns()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' ("A1:D13")
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = srg.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = srg.Resize(rCount).Offset(1).Value ' ("A2:D13")
    
    'additional code starts from here, above are just your variables you already use
    Dim MinDate As Date, MaxDate As Date
    Dim TimeSer As Date, MinDateSerial As Date, MaxDateSerial  As Date
    
    Dim MaxSerial As Double, MinSerial As Double
    
    Dim timeRng As Range
    Set timeRng = sws.Range("D1:D" & sws.Rows.Count)
    
    
    MinDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(timeRng) ' gets minimal value from column D
    MaxDate = DateAdd("h", 24, MinDate) ' just an example, how do get datetime value from another value by adding 24 hours.
    
    TimeSer = TimeSerial(10, 0, 0) ' constant 10:00:00AM later used to create min and max datetime values
    
    
    MinDateSerial = DateSerial(DatePart("yyyy", MinDate), DatePart("m", MinDate), DatePart("d", MinDate))
    MinSerial = MinDateSerial + TimeSer ' 22/04/2022  10:00:00
    
    MaxDateSerial = DateSerial(DatePart("yyyy", MaxDate), DatePart("m", MaxDate), DatePart("d", MaxDate))
    MaxSerial = MaxDateSerial + TimeSer '23/04/2022  10:00:00
   
   
    sws.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=">" & MaxSerial, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="<" & MinSerial ' filtering based on min/max datetime
    
    On Error Resume Next ' if filter will have 0 visible rows, following code will cause error.
    sws.Range("$A$2:$E$" & rCount + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete ' deletes visible rows. rCount was reduced by your initial code, so 1 is added back to get the correct last row value
    On Error GoTo 0 ' removing "Resume Next" error handler.

    sws.ShowAllData
    MsgBox ("Done")
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @NoobVB for your help.. But this didn't solve my issue.. maybe my question wasn't proper.. I want to filter every Customer exit time EVERYDAY.. so if we are checking 1st of May then I want to capture last exit status between 1st of May 10:00 AM till 11th of May 10 AM. likewise the next day.. and so on.. for all employees..

Comment: your wrote `between Time from Column D [eg: between (10AM) to next Day (10AM)]`
but the code is easy to adjust per any requirements, - the main idea is to use `TimeSerial` for filter